# Are renewables sustainable?

Tags: life-cycle-analysis

Wind and solar require steel, which is made with coal and/or natural gas to create using the Bessemer process, BOS, and other standard steelmaking practices. How do you get around this?

Comment: Related: https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/2505/15

Comment: Get around this? - You don't, not fully. But it's not as if there is no steel/coal/gas left, or that pollution and resource usage has to go down to absolute zero.

Comment: This is rather hard to answer unless you can [edit] in an explanation of what **you** mean by "sustainable" in this context. Do bear in mind that sustainability is a continuum, not a binary yes/no thing.