# What is the economic sustainability of solar power

Tags: solar-power, economy

A lot of opponents of solar power that I talk to argue that solar power is not current economically sustainable in the long term based on the energy and infrastructure required to create the panels, etc in the first place. Specifically, they say that solar panel producers use more fossil fuel in the making of this infrastructure and product than the renewable energy created in the operation of it.

How true is this claim and are there any quantitative resources for exploring both sides of this claim?

Comment: I think this has an answer here - let us know if that's the case, or not: http://sustainability.stackexchange.com/q/1013/48

Comment: I have heard the same story years ago, but I doubt that it still applies today. The answer is likely to change over time while PE cells get better and fabrication methods get more efficient.